# Как задать переменную окружения в Python

Tags: python, environment-variables

Мне нужно задать переменные окружения в python скрипте. Я хочу, чтобы все другие скрипты, вызываемые из python (shell-скрипты), которые будут дочерними процессами, видели набор переменных окружения. Значение - это число.

Когда я объявляю переменную вот так

```
os.environ ["DEBUSSY"] = 1
```

Происходит ошибка

```
TypeError: str expected, not int
```

Получается, что единица, должна быть строкой.

Я также хочу узнать, как читать переменные окружения в python (в более поздней части скрипта) после ее объявления.

Согласно [правилам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english), решил перевести [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python) со stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переменные окружения должны быть строками, поэтому используйте

```
os.environ["DEBUSSY"] = "1"
```

Чтобы получить доступ к этой переменной позже, просто используйте

```
print os.environ["DEBUSSY"]
```

Дочерние процессы автоматически наследуют среду родительского процесса - никаких специальных действий с вашей стороны не требуется.